# is it possible display: inline-flex in IE 9?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9

is it possible to Workaround for  display:inline-flex in IE 9

```
<div style="display:inline-flex"> Test </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand from your question, that you are aware of the fact that IE9 *does not support flexbox*.
A polyfill for flexbox, named [flexie.js](https://github.com/doctyper/flexie), does exist (not maintained afaik), but it works using the *old 2009 syntax* of flexbox.

Using the old syntax is of course not recommended, since the 2009 syntax is really outdated and many browsers won't recognize it anymore. *But*, you can try to use [Autoprefixer](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer), which transforms new-syntax rules to old-syntax rules (while preserving the new-syntax for browsers that do support it).

There are caveats - You won't be able to use inline-style, you would have to write your styles in CSS files, and I don't think it supports dynamic changes to the DOM.

Disclaimer: I haven't tried that method with IE9 + flexie.