# Does IE9 not support display: inline-flex at all?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, flexbox, internet-explorer-9

I've been looking around StackOverflow and even else where to find if `display: inline-flex;` works in IE9. I posted a question before this when I had trouble with expanding a width dynamically, [question here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26424869/how-to-dynamically-add-more-width-inside-a-div)

The answer helped me out, thank you who ever you are! Now that I've fixed the issue and it works fine in Chrome, Opera, Mozilla, Safari, IE10+, I still have trouble making this work in IE9.

I've also tried to add pre-fix for `display: inline-flex;` such as `display:` `-webkit-inline-box`, `-ms-inline-flexbox`, and so on.

The problem I had which fixed the whole deal was `width: auto;` and `display: inline-flex;`

Working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/g032pk1n/)

How can I make this to work in IE9?

Comment: Doesn't look like IE9 supports flexbox: http://caniuse.com/#search=flex

Comment: All right, is there any way that I can make this to work in IE9? If you look at my fiddle, you'll see that it works fine in other browsers!

Comment: This is a bit of an old post, but I came across it while looking into a solution for this (seeing as Bootstrap 4 is going fully to flexbox formatting). I came across this plugin, which seems to be maintained: https://github.com/jonathantneal/flexibility

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As you can see here: [Can I use FlexBox?](https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) Flexbox is not supported in IE9

[image: Can I use inline-flex]

**EDIT :** Based on OP comment to answer:

> if there's any way to make it work in IE9, with prefix or something?

here is a SO users' answer from another related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26360525/3448527):

> *I understand from your question, that you are aware of the fact that
>   IE9 does not support flexbox. 
>   A polyfill for flexbox, named [flexie.js](https://github.com/doctyper/flexie),
>   does exist (not maintained afaik), but it works using the old 2009
>   syntax of flexbox.*
>
> *Using the old syntax is of course not recommended,
>   since the 2009 syntax is really outdated and many browsers won't
>   recognize it anymore. But, you can try to use [Autoprefixer](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer), which
>   transforms new-syntax rules to old-syntax rules (while preserving the
>   new-syntax for browsers that do support it).*
>
> *There are caveats - You won't be able to use inline-style, you would have to write your styles in CSS files, and I don't think it supports dynamic changes to the
>   DOM.*
>
> *Disclaimer: I haven't tried that method with IE9 + flexie.*

Comment: Yes, I also visited that page and saw that flex didn't work. But my question is if there's any way to make it work in IE9, with pre-fix or something? Something that goes around, and makes it possible...

Comment: 8/9 just flat out don't support it. So not really.

Table-cell is as close as you'll get.

Comment: All right. So there's no way to make it work in IE9?

Comment: One more question though, if I use this flexie.js as you suggested, should I use it inside <!-- [if IE9]> etc...?

Comment: That's not my suggestion at all, it was only a search that I did for your question in order to try a workaround and I find that answer in another question here in SO.. but let me see about that polyfill

Comment: take a look at this demo: https://github.com/doctyper/flexie/blob/master/demo/index.html

Comment: Oh, I didn't mean it like that. But if I'm going to use this, is it the best way to keep the CSS rules inside <!-- [if IE9]>? Because I don't want my current stylesheet and javascript to collide just because I'm trying to make my timeline slider work with IE9... Do you get where I'm going?