# IE11 ignores background color in CSS

Tags: css

See this code:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="menubar">
    jsdhfsdjkfhj
  </div>
</div>
```

And this CSS:

```
.wrapper{
  display:          flex;
  flex:             1;
}

#menubar{
  min-height:           100%;
  flex:                 0 0 170px;
  background-color:     #404040;
  color:                white;
}
```

When I view the page in Chrome or Firefox, the background color of this DIV is #404040, but when I view it in IE, it is white!

Please help me solve this!

Comment: Does it work in IE if you remove the "flex" parts?

Comment: Yes, but I need the flex parts :) Edit: It works only if I remove the flex parts of .wrapper

Comment: This could help you fix the flex problem for IE http://zomigi.com/blog/flexbox-syntax-for-ie-10/ and also related to this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26490404/does-ie9-not-support-display-inline-flex-at-all

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=flex Strange, IE11 *should* be supported. Check the Known Issues section too.

Comment: Ok, so this is a known bug. Does anyone have a workaround for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by using

```
 min-height:            calc(100vh - 60px);
```

(minus 60px for the height of my header). This seems to work in all browsers that support flexbox.

Answer (score 1):

1. IE10 and IE11 default values for `flex` are `0 0 auto` rather than `0 1 auto`, as per the draft spec, as of September 2013.
2. In IE10 and IE11, containers with `display: flex` and `flex-direction: column` will not properly calculate their flexed childrens' sizes if the container has `min-height` but no explicit height property.

Comment: Okay, so the size would not be correct. However, the background color of the text "jsdhfsdjkfhj" is also white. This really is "in" this DIV, still the background-color is ignored.

Comment: `filter: none;` could save your day

Comment: Where should I add filter none? Adding it to #menubar does not help. Edit: When setting height:100% beside min-height makes it "not work" in Chrome, effect is that the div does not take the height of the full page.

Comment: I assume that something is overflowing your background and you don't see it this is what I can help from your given code EDIT: In Chrome and Safari, the height of (non flex) children are not recognized in percentages. However Firefox and IE recognize and scale the children based on percentage heights.

Comment: Consider visiting the links below your question in comments especially @gvee

Comment: Ok, so this is a known bug. Does anyone have a workaround for it?

Comment: try if statements if it is IE do this or if it is Chrome do that