# Fixed overlay with dynamic content + scrolling

Tags: html, css

This is what I am trying to accomplish:

1. A fixed container that lays over rest of page with margin.
2. Overlay container contains a header, body and footer.
3. Header and footer are sticky to top and bottom of overlay container.
4. Body has dynamic content and is supposed to be scrollable if content is larger than available space.

Here is a solution that works perfectly, if header and footer have fixed height. You also find the solution [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3bz9trzq/1/).

```css
html,
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.overlay {
    position: fixed;
    left: 30px;
    right: 30px;
    top: 30px;
    bottom: 30px;
    background-color: #f00;
}

.container {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.inner {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 60px;
    bottom: 30px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    background-color: #0f0;
}

.header {
    line-height: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #00f;
}

.footer {
    line-height: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #00f;
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header">
            Header
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            Footer
        </div>
        <div class="inner">
            Inner Content<br />
            Inner Content<br />
            Inner Content<br />
            Inner Content<br />
            Inner Content<br />
            Inner Content<br />
            Inner Content<br />
            Inner Content<br />
            Inner Content<br />
            Inner Content<br />
            Inner Content<br />
            Inner Content<br />
            Inner Content<br />
            Inner Content<br />
            Inner Content<br />
            Inner Content<br />
            Inner Content<br />
            Inner Content<br />
            Inner Content<br />
            Inner Content<br />
            Inner Content<br />
            Inner Content<br />
            Inner Content<br />
            Inner Content<br />
            Inner Content<br />
            Inner Content<br />
            Inner Content<br />
            Inner Content<br />
            Inner Content<br />
            Inner Content<br />
            Inner Content<br />
            Inner Content<br />
            Inner Content<br />
            Inner Content<br />
            Inner Content<br />
            Inner Content<br />
            Inner Content<br />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
Page Page Page Page Page Page Page Page <br />
Page Page Page Page Page Page Page Page <br />
Page Page Page Page Page Page Page Page <br />
Page Page Page Page Page Page Page Page <br />
Page Page Page Page Page Page Page Page <br />
Page Page Page Page Page Page Page Page <br />
Page Page Page Page Page Page Page Page <br />
Page Page Page Page Page Page Page Page <br />
Page Page Page Page Page Page Page Page <br />
Page Page Page Page Page Page Page Page <br />
Page Page Page Page Page Page Page Page <br />
Page Page Page Page Page Page Page Page <br />
Page Page Page Page Page Page Page Page <br />
Page Page Page Page Page Page Page Page <br />
Page Page Page Page Page Page Page Page <br />
Page Page Page Page Page Page Page Page <br />
Page Page Page Page Page Page Page Page <br />
Page Page Page Page Page Page Page Page <br />
Page Page Page Page Page Page Page Page <br />
Page Page Page Page Page Page Page Page <br />
Page Page Page Page Page Page Page Page <br />
Page Page Page Page Page Page Page Page <br />
Page Page Page Page Page Page Page Page <br />
Page Page Page Page Page Page Page Page <br />
Page Page Page Page Page Page Page Page <br />
Page Page Page Page Page Page Page Page <br />
Page Page Page Page Page Page Page Page <br />
Page Page Page Page Page Page Page Page <br />
```

**How to I accomplish the same result if header and footer were not fixed and were of dynamic content themselves?**

*I am not looking for a Javascript solution*

Comment: I'm not sure I got the question right. You mean like this? http://jsfiddle.net/3bz9trzq/2/

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but no. The header and footer should stay sticky within the overlay container.

Comment: So do you mean like this http://jsfiddle.net/m7jz8t0w/

Comment: @jcuenod: You just replaced `px` values with `%` values. That still counts for "fixed" for me. I am looking for a solution where header and footer to not have a `height` attribute attached to them.

Comment: Still not sure: this? http://jsfiddle.net/m7jz8t0w/1/ if not, try asking the question with other words

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the power of FlexBox model

```css
html,
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.overlay {
    position: fixed;
    left: 30px;
    right: 30px;
    top: 30px;
    bottom: 30px;
    background-color: #f00;
}

.container {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: stretch;
}

.inner {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    background-color: #0f0;
}

.header {
    line-height: 60px;
    background-color: #00f;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}

.footer {
    line-height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #00f;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header">
            Header
        </div>
        <div class="inner">
            Inner Content<br />
            Inner Content<br />
            Inner Content<br />
            Inner Content<br />
            Inner Content<br />
            Inner Content<br />
            Inner Content<br />
            Inner Content<br />
            Inner Content<br />
            Inner Content<br />
            Inner Content<br />
            Inner Content<br />
            Inner Content<br />
            Inner Content<br />
            Inner Content<br />
            Inner Content<br />
            Inner Content<br />
            Inner Content<br />
            Inner Content<br />
            Inner Content<br />
            Inner Content<br />
            Inner Content<br />
            Inner Content<br />
            Inner Content<br />
            Inner Content<br />
            Inner Content<br />
            Inner Content<br />
            Inner Content<br />
            Inner Content<br />
            Inner Content<br />
            Inner Content<br />
            Inner Content<br />
            Inner Content<br />
            Inner Content<br />
            Inner Content<br />
            Inner Content<br />
            Inner Content<br />
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            Footer
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
Page Page Page Page Page Page Page Page <br />
Page Page Page Page Page Page Page Page <br />
Page Page Page Page Page Page Page Page <br />
Page Page Page Page Page Page Page Page <br />
Page Page Page Page Page Page Page Page <br />
Page Page Page Page Page Page Page Page <br />
Page Page Page Page Page Page Page Page <br />
Page Page Page Page Page Page Page Page <br />
Page Page Page Page Page Page Page Page <br />
Page Page Page Page Page Page Page Page <br />
Page Page Page Page Page Page Page Page <br />
Page Page Page Page Page Page Page Page <br />
Page Page Page Page Page Page Page Page <br />
Page Page Page Page Page Page Page Page <br />
Page Page Page Page Page Page Page Page <br />
Page Page Page Page Page Page Page Page <br />
Page Page Page Page Page Page Page Page <br />
Page Page Page Page Page Page Page Page <br />
Page Page Page Page Page Page Page Page <br />
Page Page Page Page Page Page Page Page <br />
Page Page Page Page Page Page Page Page <br />
Page Page Page Page Page Page Page Page <br />
Page Page Page Page Page Page Page Page <br />
Page Page Page Page Page Page Page Page <br />
Page Page Page Page Page Page Page Page <br />
Page Page Page Page Page Page Page Page <br />
Page Page Page Page Page Page Page Page <br />
Page Page Page Page Page Page Page Page <br />
```

Comment: Just wanted to make OP know that this is not supported on ie9 http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26490404/does-ie9-not-support-display-inline-flex-at-all

Comment: Thx Philip, I did not think about flex box at all. I do not care so much about <IE10 support.